# Is it possible to create light only from a changing current in a wire?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

A changing current in a wire creates an electromagnetic field. Light can be considered an electromagnetic wave, so my question is: would it be theoretically possible to create visible light by inducing a current in a wire with a frequency inside the visible light spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, yes; in a sense, that's what a mirror reflection is, an example of
light created by the motion of electrons in the silver or aluminum metal
as a response to the incident light.   The outgoing light is, in a very real sense, newly
created by the electrons' motions, rather than being the exact same
light that impinged on the metal.

What is not generally possible, is inducing that kind of high frequency
oscillation in a long wire by driving a signal into the ends of the wire.
Conduction of electricity in long wires has too much interaction with
the (heavy) atoms, and is dominated by thermal random motions.  It's only
the thin surface of the metal that can be driven, and to get visible-light
output, it takes visible-light drive.